# Sinatra: Template engine not found: prawn

Tags: sinatra, prawn

I'm a newbie with Sinatra and prawn. I succeeded with erb and xmm/builder templates. Now trying to get pdf generation with prawn working.

Error received: `Template engine not found: prawn`

Code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/prawn'

set :prawn, { :page_layout => :portrait }

get '/pdf' do
  content_type 'application/pdf'
  prawn :pdf1
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: The gem from sbfaulkner doesn't work with current version of Sinatra.

Fix: install the forked gem from  danielberkompas as follows:

```
gem install dberkom-sinatra-prawn -s http://gems.github.com
```

See [issue 6](https://github.com/sbfaulkner/sinatra-prawn/issues/6)

Then the above code works fine.