# Sinatra + prawn example?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, prawn

I'm in the dark here. What should I do to get this thing started?

This is the closest thing I've found to a solution, but it doesn't work for me.
[Sinatra: Template engine not found: prawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135385/sinatra-template-engine-not-found-prawn)

Edit:
I'm at a very very early stage. I literally want to just try to make a hello world in Prawn, and from there I'll add my content in. Something like this (app.rb):

```
require 'prawn'

get 'report/' do
content_type 'application/pdf'

pdf = Prawn::Document.new
pdf.text "Hello World"
pdf.render

end
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question? At least provide some scope, such as whether you expect to return a dynamic PDF from a Sinatra route (a best guess). Perhaps add a skeleton piece of code with ??? where you don't know what to do. Have you tried simply returning a binary PDF, by reading it from disk? That splits your problem up into knowing how to return PDFs and knowing how to generate them . . .

Comment: @NeilSlater Thank you for responding. What I'd like to do is basically get the user to go to localhost:4567/report/ and generate a pdf which says hello world. I'll probably do things by myself after, but right now I'm at wit's end here looking for a starting point

Comment: Your example works for me (well, provided I change `get 'report/'` to `get '/report'`). I get the hello world PDF rendered inline in Chrome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code works perfectly for me, except that I had to change the path from "report/" to "/report" (because that's what Sinatra sees when you go to

```
'http://localhost:4567/report/
```

).

The exact code that I ran is:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'prawn'

get '/report/' do
  content_type 'application/pdf'

  pdf = Prawn::Document.new
  pdf.text "Hello World"
  pdf.render

end
```

and here's my ruby version:

```
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin12.2.1]
```

I think you must be incredibly close.

Comment: Turns out that I was close, I just had this route at the top of my file that was conflicting with this route. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's crazy but I solved it, finally, thanks to both of you. First, yes, there was a typo error on the preceding slash. But more importantly, what was happening was that I had a

```
get '/:model/?' do
```

line near the top of the code, and that was conflicting with this route. So I moved the report route to the top. Everything works and I can sleep now. Thank you.